When using Rush.js, How do you get a published package to update when a non-published dependency has changed?
I'm using rush with npm and have monorepo with Package A which is published (privately) and Package B which is not.
Package B is a dependency of Package A but I compile them into a single file using Rollup in my build stage before publishing.
The dependency in Package A looks something like this:
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-org/package-b": "*"
  },
  ...
}

THE QUESTION
When I update Package B, how do I get Rush to recognise that a dependency (Package B) has been updated and thus Package A has effectively changed.

Is there a configuration options for this?
Can I force rush change to generate a change file for Package A when its files haven't changed?



I'm using rush with npm

Firstly, I suggest migrate your monorepo to pnpm - rush works much better with it.
In case of pnpm usage, your deps will look like this:
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-org/package-b": "workspace:*"
  },
  ...
}


Package A which is published (privately) and Package B which is not

I guess, your rush.json file looks like this (if not, make sure it includes the following code):
...
"allowedProjectTags": ["someTag", "theSameTagOrAnotherOne"],

"projects": [
    {
      "packageName": "@my-org/package-a",
      "projectFolder": "path/to/package-a",
      "tags": ["someTag"],
      "shouldPublish": true
    },
    {
      "packageName": "@my-org/package-b",
      "projectFolder": "path/to/package-b",
      "tags": ["theSameTagOrAnotherOne"],
      "shouldPublish": false
    },
    ...
]
...

The first package "shouldPublish": true and the second one has "shouldPublish": false option to implement your words about publishing.
Important: Make sure you have added node common/scripts/install-run-rush.js change --verify line to your MR CI and Main CI pipelines. This line will fail your pipelines if soma packages are changed, but the changelog files are not provided.

When I update Package B, how do I get Rush to recognise that a dependency (Package B) has been updated and thus Package A has effectively changed.

You need to set "shouldPublish": true for package-b too.
With the mentioned setup it should work out of the box:

You are updating package-b and providing change files for this package.
Rush.js understands, that package-a depends on the package-b, but the code of package-a was not changed. So you don't need to provide manually entered change files.
Rush.js bumps the version of package-a based on the package-b change type(major/minor/patch) and adds the record about version changes to the package-a changelog by its self.


Can I force rush change to generate a change file for Package A when its files haven't changed?

The short answer is no, you can't do it out of the box. Imho, you don't really need it. If you change package-b and provide change files for it, Rush.js will automatically bump the version of package-a, add the following record to its changelog, and include it in the list of packages that should be published. But in this case, the change files are not needed for package-a from you as the code of package-a was not changed.
Example of auto-updated package-a changelog in case of changes in package-b
